# Cannot use `substring` method on an array element in `.map`

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’m trying to edit an entire array by running a function on every item in it that checks if it has a double quote as the first character and then cuts it out. The code for that looks like this:

```js
args = args.map(function(arg){
  if(arg.substring(0, 1) === "\""){
    return arg.substring(1)
  }
});
```

When I run this code I get returned with the following error:

```
index.js:97
if(arg.substring(arg.length()-1, arg.length()) === "\""){
       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
```

The parameter of a function can usually be used in an `if` statement within the function, so I don’t know why it’s returning `undefined` here. This list does have items in it.

Comment: could you add the array itself ?

Comment: What is in the array? Strings? Something else? You have to make sure that the items in the array are the type you want them to be for the ``.map`` function to work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your args array is having elements of type other than string. So make sure that the elements of the args array are strings.

If you are trying to create an array of only those elements which start with a double quote (of course after removing that double quote), `map()` is a bad choice as it will add `undefined` to the resultant array. `forEach()` would be the better choice in such case.

```
var newArgs = [];
    args.forEach(arg => {
         if(arg[0] === '"'){
              newArgs.push(arg.substring(1));
         }
    });
```

If you are trying to create an array where you will have all the elements in the args but some args elements with double quote removed (if it is the first character), then `map()` is a good choice, but it is being used in a wrong way.

```
args = args.map(function(arg){
     if(arg.substring(0, 1) === "\""){
          return arg.substring(1);
     }
    // what if the above `if` statement is false? 
    // This function is not returning anything in such case.

});
```

Correct usage would be:

`args = args.map(arg => (arg[0] === '"') ? arg.substring(1): arg);`

```js
var args = ['test1', '"test2', 'test3', '"test4', '"test5'];
var newArgs = [];
args.forEach(arg => {
     if(arg[0] === '"'){
          newArgs.push(arg.substring(1));
     }
});
console.log('forEach: ' + newArgs); 
// returns ["test2", "test4", "test5"]



// Your code in question:
newArgs = args.map(function(arg){
     if(arg.substring(0, 1) === "\""){
          return arg.substring(1);
     };
});
console.log('Your code: ' + newArgs); 
// returns [undefined, "test2", undefined, "test4", "test5"]


// If you want to get all elements but with double quote removed (if present as first character
newArgs = args.map(arg => (arg[0] === '"') ? arg.substring(1): arg);
console.log('proper map: ' + newArgs);
// returns ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

for example if you have:

`args = ["a","b",'"c"'];`

`args = args.map(arg=>arg.slice(0,1)=='"'?arg.slice(1,-1):arg)`

its return

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using the map function on an empty array. So you just need to fill the args array with some values before attempting to call map on it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have an array that looks like this `['"item1"', 'item2',  '"item3"', 'item4'];`

```
let arr = ['"item1"', 'item2',  '"item3"', 'item4'];

let newArr = arr.filter(element => (/^[^\"]/).test(element.trim()))

console.log(newArr); // item2, item4
```

Answer (score -1):

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined**

you are mapping an array which contains undefined element at certain index, now in this case before using any function you need make sure that arg is not undefined like :

```
 args = args.map(function(arg){
  if(arg!==undefined){
     if(arg.substring(0, 1) === "\""){
        return arg.substring(1)
      }
   }
 })
```

this will make sure you are not using any member function on an undefined element, hope this will help!